# How does the JPA CascadeType.PERSIST work ?

Tags: java, jpa

In my example, `Employee` has an `OneToOne` relationship to `Department` with `CascadeType.PERSIST`.
When I persist multiple `Employee`,

---

Why does the `EntityManager` persist a single `Department` record for all `Employee` records?

---

My expectation is, if we use `CascadeType.PERSIST`, when an `Employee` is being persisted, a `Department` record will be created anew for each `Employee` record.

Employee.java

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEP_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Department department;

    -----
}
```

Department.java

```
@Entity
public class Department implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

Test.java

```
public void insert() {
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Department department = new Department("Test Department");
    for(int i=1; i <= 10; i++) {
        Employee e = new Employee("EMP" + i, department);
        em.persist(e);
    }
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}
```

Result :

```
Employee Table          Department Table
=================       ==============================
ID  Name  DEP_ID        ID      NAME    
=================       ==============================
1   EMP1    1           1       Test Department
2   EMP2    1
3   EMP3    1
4   EMP4    1
5   EMP5    1
6   EMP6    1
7   EMP7    1
8   EMP8    1
9   EMP9    1
10  EMP10   1
```

Comment: I would expect that DEP_ID would have UNIQUE constraint because of the OneToOne annotation (Just like the Many-side of a JOIN table for a OneToMany association has a UNIQUE constraint on it). Can anyone explain why DEP_ID doesn't have a UNIQUE constraint in this case, despite the OneToOne annotation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JPA maintains object identity and will not persist an existing object.

Change you code to be correct,

```
for(int i=1; i <= 10; i++) {
    Department department = new Department("Test Department");
    Employee e = new Employee("EMP" + i, department);
    em.persist(e);
}
```

Comment: yes, I know, your coding will work. You create new instance of `Department` for all of `Employee`. What was wrong my understanding?

Comment: Because you have one to one mapping from Employee to Department, not many to one.

Comment: It would be interesting to also get an answer to the question on "How does the JPA CascadeType.PERSIST work?". As this is the reason I looked at the question.

Comment: CascadeType.PERSIST just cascades for persist method. If you delete or merge your parent entity, the related child entity wouln't be touched.