# Bind form and save data to 2 tables

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a fairly simple contact form that collects basic contact information along with a list of website(s).

The Contact model has a FK relation to a Website table. When I bind the form and save I would also like to save any website entries in the Website table.

Is the binding of a form one to one with a table, 1 form class binds to 1 model or can a form when bound also access models where a FK exists?

**Contact Model:**

```
@Entity
public class Contact extends Model {

public static Model.Finder<Long, Contact> finder = new Model.Finder<Long, Contact>(Long.class, Contact.class);
public static Finder<String,Contact> find = new Finder<String,Contact>(String.class, Contact.class);

public Contact(String prefix, String firstName, String lastName, String company, String title, String primaryEmail, String primaryPhone, Collection<Website> websites){
    this.prefix = prefix;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.company = company;
    this.title = title;
    this.primaryEmail = primaryEmail;
    this.primaryPhone = primaryPhone;
    this.websites = new LinkedList<Website>(websites);

}

@Id
public Long id;

public String prefix;

@Constraints.Required
@Constraints.MinLength(2)
@Constraints.MaxLength(25)
public String firstName;

@Constraints.Required
@Constraints.MinLength(2)
@Constraints.MaxLength(25)
public String lastName;

public String company;

public String title;

public String ledes;

@Constraints.Email
@Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(50)")
public String primaryEmail;

@Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(30)")
public String primaryPhone;

@Formats.NonEmpty
@Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 1")
@OneToOne
public ContactType contactType;

@ManyToOne
public Firm firm;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "contact")
public List<Matter> matter = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact")
public List<Child> child = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact")
public List<Location> location = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact")
public List<Phone> phone = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact")
public List<Email> email = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact")
public List<Website> websites = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact")
public List<InstantMessenger> messenger = new ArrayList<>();


@Column(name = "created_at")
public Date createdAt;

@Column(name = "updated_at")
public Date updatedAt;

@Override
public void save() {
    createdAt();
    super.save();
}

@Override
public void update() {
    updatedAt();
    super.update();
}

@PrePersist
void createdAt() {
    this.createdAt = this.updatedAt = new Date();
}

@PreUpdate
void updatedAt() {
    this.updatedAt = new Date();
}



}
```

**Website Model:**

```
@Entity
public class Website extends Model {


public Website() {

}

public Website(String website, String websiteType) {
    this.website = website;
    this.websiteType = websiteType;
}

@Id
public Long id;

@Required
@URL
@MaxLength(100)
@Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(100) not null")
public String website;

@Required
@MaxLength(20)
@Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(20) not null")
public String websiteType;

@Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 1")
public Boolean isActive;

@Column(name = "created_at")
public Date createdAt;

@Column(name = "updated_at")
public Date updatedAt;

@Override
public void save() {
    createdAt();
    super.save();
}

@Override
public void update() {
    updatedAt();
    super.update();
}

@PrePersist
void createdAt() {
    this.createdAt = this.updatedAt = new Date();
}

@PreUpdate
void updatedAt() {
    this.updatedAt = new Date();
}

@ManyToOne()
public Contact contact;

}
```

**Contacts Controller:**

```
public class Contacts extends Controller {



@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
public Result allContacts() {
    return ok(contactsAll.render(
            Contact.finder.where().gt("id", 0).findList()
    ));
}

@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
public Result newContact() {
    return ok(contactNew.render(form(Contact.class)));
}

@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
public Result addContact() {
    play.data.Form<Contact> contactForm = form(Contact.class).bindFromRequest();

    if (contactForm.hasErrors()) {
        flash("error", "Please correct the form below.");
        return ok(contactNew.render(contactForm));
    } else {

        // Bind form and save
        Contact contact = contactForm.get();
        contact.save();

//            if (contactForm.get().websites != null) {
//                new Website(contactForm.get().websites).save();
//            }

        flash("success", String.format("Successfully added %s", contactForm.get().firstName + ' ' + contactForm.get().lastName));


        return redirect(
                routes.Contacts.allContacts()
        );
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the: 
This [guy explains, how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907942/how-does-the-jpa-cascadetype-persist-work)

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

Annotation.

This will save the page as well ( at least in my app it does )

If this doesn't work.

You can access the page like so:

```
Contact.webpage
```

That means, that you could also do:

```
Contact.webpage = contactForm.get().websites
contact.save();
```

You called the save action, before you set the webpage.